# How to calculate sum of timestamps and then to perform percentage of time spent

Tags: sql

I am working on SQL for my report from past few days, but now I am stuck on this problem.

Scenario: I have user who has worked for some hours. I want to know percentage of time spent particular work.

Table details:

```
user  work      allocated_time        completed_time      time    %age_of_work
amit  operation 24-jul-200810:35:00   24-jul-200811:42:00 1:7:0   ?
amit  research  24-jul-200812:00:00   24-jul-200802:42:00 2:42:0  ?
```

Percentage of work is how much time he spent for operation and research on 24 July. Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are asking how to write a query but it is difficult to answer if we don't know what RDBMS you are using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostGreSQL, SQLite…) and what version of that RDBMS. Their implementation of SQL differ and there are features that we could use to improve the query efficiency for example. Also, SQL syntax can vary. For this particular question also, please state what is the type affinity for the timestamp columns (DATE, TEXT)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you can't sum a `TIME` type in SQL.

Instead you might want to calculate the time spent as minutes (or seconds, if necessary).

Try something like this:

```
declare @table table 
(
    [user] nvarchar(50),
    [work] nvarchar(50),
    [allocated_time] datetime,
    [completed_time] datetime
)

insert @table values ('amit', 'operation', '24-jul-2008 10:35:00PM', '24-jul-2008 11:42:00PM')
insert @table values ('amit', 'research', '24-jul-2008 12:00:00PM', '24-jul-2008 02:42:00PM')

declare @totalminutes int

select @totalminutes = sum([minutes]) 
from (select DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [allocated_time], [completed_time]) as [minutes] from @table) t

select *, 
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [allocated_time], [completed_time]) as [minutes],
    CONVERT(FLOAT, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, [allocated_time], [completed_time])) / @totalminutes as [perc]
from @table
```

Comment: pleasure benoit... as query  mentioned above kirk that didn't work